# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I know there are a lot of similar questions to this one around Stack Overflow but none of them can answer my problem.

This is a line from my stored procedure:

```
SET @AdIDNumber = PARSENAME(REPLACE(@AdIDNumber, '-', '.'), 1);
```

`ADIDNumber` is a parameter being passed into this stored procedure. I'm trying to get the last component of the `ADIDNumber` `nvarchar` separated by `'-'`. I am getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

The strange thing is, it doesn't happen every time. Here are some `ADIDNumbers` that work:

```
188CR-000O-000199
188CR-000D-000105
```

and some that cause an error:

```
188CR-000A-000505
188CR-000S-001459
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Here is my whole stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getOutlookDetails]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@CountryName nvarchar(max),
@CommunityName nvarchar(max),
@AdIDNumber nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @dbName nvarchar(max);
-- remove spaces
SET @CountryName = LOWER(REPLACE(@CountryName, ' ', ''));
SET @CommunityName = LOWER(REPLACE(@CommunityName, ' ', ''));


SET @dbName = @CountryName;
IF @CommunityName IS NOT NULL
    SET @dbName = @dbName+'_'+@CommunityName;

IF DB_ID(@dbname) IS NULL
    BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Database not found',16,1)
    RETURN
    END

DECLARE @tab AS TABLE (AdName nvarchar(max), OwnerJALName nvarchar(max), OwnerEmail nvarchar(max), AdContactEmail nvarchar(max), 
                  AdWebsiteLink nvarchar(max), Ad1stPhone nvarchar(max), Ad2ndPhone nvarchar(max), VideoUrl nvarchar(max), 
                  AdBusinessType nvarchar(max), AdBusinessLocation nvarchar(max), 
                  PublishStatus INTEGER, MediaGalleryEnabled INTEGER, MapTabEnabled nvarchar(max),
                  MapCategory nvarchar(max), VMEnabled INTEGER);

-- format the PostID
SET @AdIDNumber = PARSENAME(REPLACE(@AdIDNumber, '-', '.'), 1); 

-- we fill the table with LocationCoordinates in the MapCategory column twice so we can replace it later
DECLARE @dynsql nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @PostIDInt INTEGER;
SET @PostIDInt = CAST(@AdIDNumber AS INTEGER);
SET @dynsql = N'USE '+ QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N' SELECT dbo.cs_Posts.Subject, dbo.cs_Users.UserName, dbo.cs_Users.Email, dbo.drive_DirectoryPosts.ContactEmail, 
                  dbo.drive_DirectoryPosts.ContactWebsite, dbo.drive_DirectoryPosts.ContactPhone, dbo.drive_DirectoryPosts.ContactPhoneOther, dbo.drive_DirectoryPosts.VideoUrl, 
                  dbo.drive_DirectoryPosts.ContactBusinessType, dbo.drive_DirectoryPosts.ContactBusinessLocation, 
                  dbo.drive_DirectoryPosts.IsActive, dbo.drive_DirectoryPosts.IsMediaGalleryActive, 
                  dbo.drive_DirectoryPosts.LocationCoordinates, dbo.drive_DirectoryPosts.LocationCoordinates, dbo.drive_DirectoryPosts.IsMediaGalleryActive
                  FROM dbo.drive_DirectoryPosts INNER JOIN
                  dbo.cs_Posts ON dbo.drive_DirectoryPosts.PostID = dbo.cs_Posts.PostID INNER JOIN
                  dbo.cs_Users ON dbo.cs_Posts.UserID = dbo.cs_Users.UserID
                  WHERE dbo.cs_Posts.PostID = @PostIDInt';

INSERT INTO @tab EXECUTE sp_executesql @dynsql, N'@PostIDInt INTEGER', @PostIDInt = @PostIDInt;

DECLARE @MapCategory nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @VMEnabled INTEGER;
EXEC [dbo].sp_getMapCategory @dbName, @PostIDInt, @MapCategory OUTPUT, @VMEnabled OUTPUT;

UPDATE @tab SET MapCategory = @MapCategory;
UPDATE @tab SET VMEnabled = @VMEnabled;
SELECT * FROM @tab;
```

Comment: You're abusing `PARSENAME` - it's not intended for general parsing purposes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for replying. Would that be causing this error? What should i be using instead? Incase you can't tell im new to all this SQL stuff.

Comment: I don't think you've shown enough code - It's complaining of an issue converting to `uniqueidentifier`, but I don't *think* that `@AdIDNumber` could be declared as such, since otherwise you couldn't get e.g. `188CR-000D-000105` in there in the first place.

Comment: Its not, @AdIDNumber is declared as an nvarchar(max).

Comment: Then you need to show the code where the conversion error is actually occurring. `188CR` is not a valid character sequence in a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, ever, so it isn't possible that those "sometimes work"...

Comment: Ok, i've edited the question to include my whole stored procedure.

Comment: Still no `uniqueidentifier` in the code. Could the error come from `sp_getMapCategory`?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson that was it. The error was being caused by the sp_getMapCategory procedure. I've managed to fix it now. Not sure why I thought it was the AdIDNumber. Thanks for all your help anyway!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It was caused by the sp_getMapCategory stored procedure.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it needs more explanation. No on knows what is in that SP that made it go wrong. If a better explanation is added I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
DECLARE @AdIDNumber VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @AdIDNumber='188CR-000O-000199'
DECLARE @REVERSE VARCHAR(MAX)=REVERSE(@AdIDNumber)
select REVERSE(LEFT(@REVERSE,CHARINDEX('-',@REVERSE)-1))
```

Comment: Um. That measures the distance from the start of the string to the *first* `-` character, then uses that to count the number of characters to keep from the right-hand side. That doesn't sound right.

Comment: Did not see that. Sorry about that. Updated the answer